# Change Firefox 4 UI to Firefox 3 UI?

Tags: firefox, gui

Any quick way to change Firefox 4 UI to the old Firefox UI? I am on Windows, and I just can't live with the new Firefox GUI layout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click Menu bar -> put a check against Menu bar

Before ->

[image]

After doing the change

[image]

Comment: sweet @Sathya! nice and simple... +1

Comment: Couldn't be any easier :) Thank you so much!  Also just wanted to add that in Customize Toolbar window I switched to Icons and Text to make the Reload and Stop buttons bit larger if anyone needs that.

Comment: Note that you can also put the tabs below the location bar again. Right-click the menu bar and uncheck *Tabs on top*. This (re-)enables features such as double-clicking the tab bar to open a new tab or F6 to get the focus into the location bar.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend the [Lifehacker article](http://lifehacker.com/#!5784783/how-to-fix-annoyances-with-firefox-4s-new-look) on this. Mine certainly easier to use after implementing some of their tips.